# eclipse error "android.jar" missing

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I'm trying to import my android projects to my new pc. but eclipse fires the following error-

"Project 'MyProject' is missing required library: 'C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-10\android.jar' Build path Build Path Problem.

but there is no folder called 'C:\Users\myName\AppData~", my user folder is 'C:\Users\PC\AppData~.

how to fix this guys??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delete the android.jar from Project->Properties->Java Build Path

Comment: @amitsharma Glad it helped :) Btw I will suggest you to move on Android Studio now. Eclipse is outdated for android development.

Answer (score 2):

Right click on AndEngine go to Properties ->Android select Android 4.03 and click ok . This will build your project in Android 4.03 and get the required Andengine.jar file.

Answer (score 1):

Change your computer name to "myName".

Comment: changed to myName. but the path is still C:\Users\PC\AppData~. new projects are working perfectly. i'm using windows 8 pro with latest android developer tools.

Answer (score 1):

I also came across this kind of issue occationally, doing clean or selecting android project build target doesn't work, restart eclipse works though.

Answer (score 1):

Your sdk have missing `.jar` file
Download `android.jar` file from https://github.com/Sable/android-platforms and paste it.
It will work fine on `Windows` and `Linux`